# Transferring product information from excel into a catalogue in InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns of product names and descriptions all to transfer into indesign for a product catalogue. They will be all in indivudual text boxes per product. There are quite a few so I am trying to figure out what the easiest way to do it was. I have done data merge before but there will be multiple products on a spread so in this case I don't think it will work because it will generate a page for each row.I also don't really want to create a table for them as I would like to keep the text boxes easy to move around so that I can change the layout if needed.

Comment: It's hard to give a precise answer when it's unclear exactly what kind of result you want. I would probably just copy/paste the data from the spread sheet to a temporary InDesign document and manipulate it into a form I can use with Find/Replace and by converting the text to a table and back again depending on the data and what I want to do with it. Perhaps style it in one big text frame and use a script to chop it into individual text frames.